# What is the option to "append" in Logback RollingFileAppender?

Tags: java, logback

I have a simple question for using logback.
I am using Logback for my application with RollingFileAppender.
It works well but when I restart my application, It won't append existing file but gone somewhere.

Here is xml file for logback configuration for my application.

```
 <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- hourly rollover -->
        <fileNamePattern>/home/log/logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <!-- or whenever the file size reaches 100MB -->
            <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        <!-- keep 30 hours' worth of history -->
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%-4r [%thread] %X{clientIP} %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%p] [%thread@%C{1}:%L] - %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

For example, when I first start application, It creates a log file in accordance with configuration above.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      6926 Nov  7 10:19 logFile.2015-11-07.log
```

But if I stop application and restart, I expect log to be appended on above file but It won't ( I even couldn't find where this missing log exist. )

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188936/timebasedrollingpolicy-not-rolling-unless-there-are-new-logs Short version: It's not time-triggered, but logging-event-triggered. No logging events means no rollover. In a configuration set to rollover each minute that means there will be no files for any minute for which no logging-events arrive.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html) states

> Note that the `file` property in `RollingFileAppender` (the parent of
> `TimeBasedRollingPolicy`) can be either set or omitted. By setting the
> file property of the containing `FileAppender`, you can decouple the
> location of the active log file and the location of the archived log
> files. **The current logs will be always targeted at the file specified
> by the `file` property.** It follows that the name of the currently active
> log file will not change over time. **However, if you choose to omit the
> file property, then the active file will be computed anew for each
> period based on the value of `fileNamePattern`.**

By *computed anew*, they mean that a new file will be created (or an existing one truncated).

So just provide an appropriately named `file` property.

```xml
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>/home/log/logFile.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- hourly rollover -->
        <fileNamePattern>/home/log/logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <!-- or whenever the file size reaches 100MB -->
            <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        <!-- keep 30 hours' worth of history -->
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%-4r [%thread] %X{clientIP} %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%p] [%thread@%C{1}:%L] - %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

With `file`, you're telling Logback which is the active file and therefore which to append to (after determining if a rollover is necessary).